# How to implement place auto-complete using nominatim?

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

I want to auto complete like Google Place but I don't want to use Google Place API. I got nominatim auto-complete example but it's not working in  Windows 8 because it's implemented in node.js

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using Nominatim for for Autocompletion might be not the best idea. If you using the osm.org nominatim Server the [usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy) forbid using Nominatim for Autocompletion:

> Auto-complete search: This is not yet supported by Nominatim and you must not implement such a service on the client side using the API.

Also it is not really useful to use Nominatim for autocompletion, because if you type "Ber" you would expect something like "Berlin" but Nominatim searches for places exactly known as "Ber" and suggests "Ber, Tombouctou, Timbuktu, Mali".

But there are some OpenStreetMap based geocoders with autocompletion support like [Photon](http://photon.komoot.de/) and [Pelias](https://github.com/pelias/pelias) ([Demo](https://mapzen.com/pelias)). There are usage examples on the project sites.

Comment: Some updates on Pelias: https://github.com/pelias/pelias/tree/master/announcements/2018-01-02-pelias-update/

Comment: Not sure why Nominatim bans autocompletion in their ToU. Are they worried about receiving too many requests? It's easy enough for the client to debounce its requests to, say, max once a second. And Nominatim must have some rate-limiter for their API.